# How to operate tube-lights using relays

Tags: relay, ac, light

I am using the circuit mentioned in one of the articles of EFY ([Ref.](http://areptone.com/arefy/Device%20%20Control%20through%20pc%20lptport.pdf)) .I have added the freewheeling diode across the relay, and I am able to turn On/Off bulbs as well as CFLs successfully.Now I want to switch a tube light(one with choke and starter),using  the same circuit,how should I it?

When I tried switching tube light,the relay connected to it operates properly,the 230V are also properly transferred to the input wires of light(measured using multimeter),but some how the other light is not getting switched on.

PS: When i tried different tubelights, some of them are working and some are not,so this is some other issue than ratings(btw I am using 40W-220v tubes).

Comment: no answers yet.!

Comment: SO I understand you are using a 230V passive Ballast switched by a relay? Is the relay rated for high voltage? Does it have any noise suppression on the coil? Do you have ballast model#?

Comment: Whom is EFY by the way?

Comment: @Kortuk EFY = Electronics For You,is that what you were asking?

Comment: What, exactly, it a "Tube Light"? Is that a odd way to refer to a typical fluorescent light?

Comment: @buch11, yes, I have never heard of them before.

Comment: @FakeName yes they are the same

Comment: @Kortuk Ok thats a monthly magazine(as you might already have googled it).

Comment: Provide a schematic diagram or a working link to the magazine article.  Else your verbal description of your circuit is vulnerable to the same faulty assumptions that is making the circuit fail.  Nobody recognizes "tubelight" and it is a very ambiguous name. We think you are asking about a conventional fluorescent lamp with 40W tubes.  The fluorescent tubes are NOT rated for the supply voltage, it is the ballast that handles the mains voltage. The tubes are the same regardless of mains voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your circuit has to do with anything if it eventually just operates a relay that applies power to the light.  There is nothing more the circuit can do other than switch the relay as intended.

To the light, it doesn't matter whether the power is switched thru a relay or a switch on the wall.  If the light is intended to run on th 230 V you mention, and you can verify that this is applied accross the light, then the rest is up to the light.  230 V is 230 V, whether switched thru a relay, a light switch on the wall, or directly connected to the power line.

Does the light work if you connect power to it directly?  If not, the light is broken.  If it does, than the relay isn't properly switching on or it's not hooked up right.  What is the current rating of the relay contacts?  What is the light's current rating?

Comment: Yes the light works as it should if I connect it directly to 220V mains,The relay is also hooked up properly as i change the light with a bulb(pure resistive load),bulb is getting turned on/off through the same relay.Currently i am away but i'll update my question to include light and relay's ratings.

Comment: updated the question sir